# Unable to connect to Redis running a Junit Test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, redis, junit4

I have a basic SpringBoot 2.0.4.RELEASE app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file, and I don't use any Redis configuration at all

I have created this Junit Test:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestSystemConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AzureApplication.class) 
public class RoleServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    protected  RoleService  roleService;


    @Test
    public void testSaveAndFindByName() throws Exception {

        roleService.save(new Role(RolesEnum.ADMIN));
        assertNotNull (roleService.findByName(RolesEnum.ADMIN.getRoleName()));

    }
}
```

But when I run the test I got this Exception:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to localhost:6379
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:966)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:934)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.execute(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.DefaultRedisCacheWriter.get(DefaultRedisCacheWriter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCache.lookup(RedisCache.java:82)
    at org.springframework.cache.support.AbstractValueAdaptingCache.get(AbstractValueAdaptingCache.java:58)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.AbstractCacheInvoker.doGet(AbstractCacheInvoker.java:73)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findInCaches(CacheAspectSupport.java:525)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:490)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:372)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:316)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy131.getByName(Unknown Source)
```

but the other Junit tests like this are running fine:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={TestSystemConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = AzureCloudApplication.class) 
public class CompanyServiceTests {

    @Autowired
    protected  CompanyService  companyService;


    @Test
    public void testFindAll() throws Exception {

        Iterable<Company> companies = companyService.findAll();
        assertTrue (((Collection<?>) companies).size() > 0);            
    }


    @Test
    public void testCompanyUsers() throws Exception {

        Iterable<Company> companies = companyService.findAll();
        Company company = companies.iterator().next();

        assertNotNull (company);

        company = companyService.companyUsers(company.getId());
        assertTrue (((Collection<?>) company.getUsers()).size() > 0);           
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the questioned tests are using services which have relation with redis.
Because of that you need to mock redis.
You can check helpful blog post mentinoned [here](https://www.tikalk.com/posts/2017/08/07/unit-and-integration-tests-for-java-redis/) about this situation.
Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464043/skip-mock-redis-in-junit) question on stackoverflow.